# Adding generated script file after angular build to index.html

Tags: javascript, angular, build

image 1 [file i want to added in index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWCzK.png)    image 2 [index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5MmLj.png)After the angular build there are many javascript files generated in dist/ , But some javascript file is not getting added in index.html . How can i add those js file in index.html ?

Name generated everytime is different after every build something like
file1.[hash_value].js .

Comment: Just edit the index.html in your src directory

Comment: Generated js file name is not fixed its everytime different like 'hello.[hash_value].js' so everytime we do the build its name is different .

Comment: who is generating the file,

Comment: I have attached one image in that you can see some script file is added in index.html after the build , But I want to add some more script file which has similar names in index.html , which is not added automatically ? I think webpack is generating those files .

Comment: Please help how can i add those script in html file because name generated is different after every build . 
Thanks in advance .

Comment: Why don't you add them in your angular.json configuration ? There is the `scripts` section dedicated to doing just that. https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config#style-script-config